# Nginx https error

Tags: nginx, https, nginx-location

I´m trying to setup nginx HTTPS on my host, but gets a error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:7
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Conf:

```
   server {
listen 443 ssl;              
              server_name quickseed.me;
             ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/quickseed.me/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/quickseed.me/privkey.pem;
}
  root /var/www/html/;
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
location /phpmyadmin {
  root /usr/share/;
  index index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
    deny all;
  }
  location ~ /phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should put location under a server directive. Try this code.

```
server {
      listen 443 ssl;              
      server_name quickseed.me;
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/quickseed.me/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/quickseed.me/privkey.pem;

      root /var/www/html/;
      index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
  location /phpmyadmin {
     root /usr/share/;
     index index.php;
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~ /phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.